# VPN list strange behaviour

Tags: vpn

Love Elementary OS - after years of trying different Linux flavours this is the one that has finally tempted me away from Windows 7.

I've noted a strange behaviour in the VPN connections list - I have multiple connections in the list. If there is an active connection, and I accidentally click on one of the inactive connections both are removed from the list until the settings app is closed and reopened. In one instance, the active connection was duplicated in the list after reopening, leaving me with two identical VPN configurations in the list.

This is not a big problem - it has no functional impact that I can see, but it's a strange behaviour. I'd also love to see a VPN connection list under the right-click context menu for network connections in the wing panel, in a future version.

Maybe someone can also tell me how to contribute financially to the development of Elementary now it's my regular OS.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question check out: https://elementary.io/get-involved#funding

As for your first one, you might want to file a bug report instead.